# Is there a way to create a testing environment in Sales-force Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, unit-test, salesforce1-app

Making changes in production for my templates and seeking ideas on creating a testing environment before moving to production. Maybe there is an app I could have my company install.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no QA or developer environments on Marketing Cloud. What you can do is that you can create a QA Business Unit, implement and test all the functionality on that BU and then migrate all the stuff to a Production BU.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [testing/sandbox environment](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf) available, but it costs extra $$$ - like most things do in Salesforce. I HAVE heard of people being able to negotiate this for free, but that was before it was on the official documentation.

If you don't want to pay for the testing environment, then my recommendation would be to do like Sanchit mentioned and create a DEV/UAT environment via a BU. This, unfortunately, will still cost you for each message you send, each API/Automation you use, and each subscriber you store will still go towards your total DE storage and so on - as it would in your Production environment.

If you are looking to just test display/cross-browser support on emails, I would check out [litmus](https://litmus.com/) or [Email on Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/) as they can provide you with screen shots of each email in dozens of browsers and email clients.

Comment: thanks, coz this is quite an old answer, are there any change now? I used to have 1 BU per environment (1 test/1 for prod...)

Comment: @eeadev There is no more testing/sandbox environment specific purchasable item anymore - to have a fully separate testing environment you either need to create a new BU that is not connected to your parent BU or you need a completely different enterprise edition that is fully separate. Neither of which is cheap.

Comment: @Gortonington - I'm currently considering the business unit route for testing, with shared content assets and duplicated triggered send definitions, API events etc with an environment suffix to differentiate. Does this approach scale well with hundreds/thousands of activities?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not. Here is the [Exact Target DE Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ) that you can vote on